# What's the meaning of the expression "[something] much?"

Tags: meaning, slang

I think I encountered the expression or so, some number of times. I don't understand what it means. Just a noun followed by "much?". I don't understand the meaning of the expression, I'm thinking. (edit) Maybe it's not formal language or so? Not sure.

I'm thinking, mostly I've got the following examples in mind. Below are some of the titles of some episodes of the show [*Totally Spies!*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Totally_Spies!_episodes#Season_3:_2004.E2.80.9305)

- Physics 101 Much?
- Freaky Circus Much?
- Computer Creep Much?
- Evil Coffee Shop Much?
- Super Nerd Much?

Comment: I learned this expession on The Office. "Walk much?" was used in event of tripping into the koi pond.
On Pam and Jim's wedding after Jim cut his tie was asked "Tie much?". Still kinda I understand that, but I wouldn't be able to come up with this experssion on that event.
As well as I heard "Talk much?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am pretty sure it's this slang usage:

> **much**
>
> When we say sentences like 'Walk much?' **we shorten** 'Do you walk much?'
>
> VERB + much
>
> ADJECTIVE + much
>
> NOUN + much
>
> ADJECTIVE and NOUN + much
>
> etc.
>   *Confused, much?*
>
> *Off message much?*
>
> 466 122 [that's a pretty good score: for/against this reading]
>
> [**Urban Dictionary**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=much)

I don't know the show, but perhaps:

*Physics 101 Much? =Do you like Physics 101 Much?*

*Computer Creep Much? = Is she/he Much of a Computer Creep, you think?*

Comment: I believe it started as a sarcastic comment - as in, "Complain much?" Regardless, this answer is correct. +1

Answer (score 9):

The expression ***x* much** is a sarcastic expression meaning that the target of the expression is engaging in *x*, and is generally used when *x* is undesirable.

An example: Susan is about to leave work at 5:00 on a Friday, and has weekend plans.  Just before she heads out, her boss approaches her and asks her to complete a big project by Monday.  Susan might say to her boss, "Unreasonable much?"

Another example: a group of friends are eating at a cafe.  Most of them are happy, enjoying the food and company.  One has been finding fault all evening, saying that the service is slow, the place too loud, the soup was cold, the appetizer oversalted, and the main course overcooked.  Someone else at the table might sarcastically ask "complain much?"

Comment: A real example: https://dilbert.com/strip/2019-03-19

Comment: A prominent comics artist posted a picture that reminded me of another artist, and I teased him with “Druillet much?”  He took it in good humor.

Answer (score 5):

Most commonly, "x much?" is used when the person being addressed is displaying too much x (where x is something bad). For example, someone might say "hypocrisy much?" in response to someone who's said something hypocritical or is acting that way. It's also used with nouns that describe people, so "um, stalker much?" could be used to call out someone for their creepy behavior (where they're acting like a stalker). And it's used with verbs too, like "blame the victim much?" when someone's doing exactly that.

More rarely, "x much?" is used to respond to someone who's acting like they have no x, where x is something desirable. For example, someone spouting a confused explanation might be told "logic much?"

(The examples in the question seem to be mostly of the former type, but "Physics 101 Much?" probably is the latter.)

Either way, it's sarcastic, flippant, and rude enough that I would recommend **not** saying it to someone's face. Note that legitimate questions may have some elision, but not to this extent. For example, "you drive much?" (dropping *do*) is a legitimate question while "drive much?" is accusing them of driving poorly.

Note: Most of these are real examples from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) — try the search `NOUN much ?`

Answer (score 1):

Using that expression is often sarcastic, as jetset said, but I think it has more to do with someone's ineptitude in the matter.  So for example, "Physics 101 Much?" might be in response to someone saying or doing something stupid that is covered in basic physics.  Perhaps someone just said that heavier objects always fall faster than lighter objects.

Or if someone failed at lifting a heavy object, one might say "Lift much?"